# Not asking to kill a dead process?

Tags: process, compilation, compilation-mode, subprocess

When I hit <kbd>g</kbd> ([`recompile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html)) in a `*Compilation*` buffer while the previous compilation is not done yet, I am asked whether I want compilation killed. If I wait for it to finish, I get the echo area look like this:

```
A compilation process is running; kill it? (y or n) [Compilation finished]
```

It would be nice if as soon as the compilation finished, the question automatically disappeared and the compilation restarted.

I looked at the source code, but I see not simple way to make it happen.

**NB1**. Of course, this requested change should also affect `process-kill-buffer-query-function`...

**NB2**. `compilation-always-kill` is **not** what I want: it kills the compilation right away. I want Emacs *not to wait for my permission to kill an already dead process*.

Comment: `compilation-always-kill` may help

Comment: @shynur - see NB2